# Is it a sexual offence for a 53-year-old to have sex with a nine-year-old, even if they are purportedly married?

Tags: united-states, european-union, sexual-offences

The facts:

- a 53-year-old is purportedly married to a 9-year-old and intercourse is happening
- neither of the purported spouses, their parents, nor their acquaintances have expressed any complaints about the situation
- the two purported spouses are citizens of a country in Asia but live in either North America or the EU permanently.

According to North American, British or EU law, is the 53-year-old committing a sexual offence?

Comment: In the United States, *somebody* did something they shouldn't: no state permits a six-year-old to get married.  Either somebody successfully passed a six-year-old off as being much older, or someone wasn't paying attention when they handled the paperwork.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is being posed for an improper purpose and a manner that any answer is likely to be used out of context in a manner that is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as "EU" law. Each member state has their own laws.

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) it is not forbidden to live together. The marriage certainly would not be legal here and I highly doubt the marriage would be recognized here if legalized somewhere else.

But let's for the sake of the argument assume it would be. As soon as it gets into territory that marriage is made for, it would be highly illegal. Moving to a different country from Asia, the minor is highly dependent on their adult spouse for basically everything. Starting with mandatory health insurance, where you literally have to check the box "a dependent of the adult" in the adults insurance, to basic needs such as food, shelter, clothes, paying for school materials. Even in theory, with school being mandatory and laws against child labor, there is no way the child would not be depending on that adult.

> § 174 Abs. 1 StGB
> Sex mit Schutzbefohlenen (Personen unter 16 Jahren, die
> jemandem zur Erziehung, Ausbildung oder zur Betreuung in
> der Lebensführung anvertraut sind bzw. leibliche oder angenommene Kinder unter 18 Jahren) und Sex unter Missbrauch
> eines Abhängigkeitsverhältnisses ist verboten und wird mit
> Freiheitsstrafe bis zu 5 Jahren bestraft.

Translation:

> Sex with a protected person (a person under the age of 16 who is
> entrusted to someone for upbringing, education or
> persons under the age of 16 who are entrusted to the care of someone for upbringing, education, or life care, or natural or adopted children under the age of 18) and sex in abuse of a relationship of dependence in general is prohibited and is punishable by imprisonment for up to 5 years.

That is if they *agreed*.

If they *don't*, it's rape, plain and simple, regardless of marital status or other relationship and will, depending on circumstances, net you something between the 5 years above up to 15 years in prison. The difference between raping a spouse and raping someone outside of marriage has been abolished in 1997.

Comment: This answer is unclear. What does a "protected person" have to do with "marriage"?

Comment: @user366312 Since 2017 a marriage is not possible if one or both are minors (less than 18). If a 3rd country national takes up residence in Germany and was married abroad as a minor, that marriage will not be recognised if one of the parties are still a minor when they take up their residence in Germany.  The minor is therefore a "protected person".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question before edits: I assume the wedding was done in Asia. For example, after the girls parents died, a good family friend decided to look after her, found it very difficult to legally adopt her and surprisingly found he could marry her. With the intention that she would be looked after, could go to school, live in comfort, and inherit should he die.

Most likely the marriage wouldn’t be legally acknowledged in the USA. It is entirely possible for these two people to live in the same home without a crime happening, that’s what happens in most homes after all. A marriage in another country that isn’t acknowledged is not a crime, nor is living in the same house.

PS. Hours later the poster adds that something happened that would be a crime… Why couldn’t you post that first?

Comment: @gnasher Re: your post script: Technically they did, the question has been edited several times.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to nvoigts answer:
It would be illegal in Germany to have sex with a person under 14 (the age of consent) anyway, regardless if it's a protected person.
Technically even two 13 year olds having sex would be illegal, though the age of criminal responsibility is also 14, so they couldn't held responsible for the act.

Answer (score -1):

From the perspective of US law, and where more specificity is needed, California law:

"Is the 53 year old who marries a 6 year old (setting aside that such a marriage can't happen in the US, because a 6 year old can't marry anywhere in the US) guilty of any crime for that act alone".

No. Getting married is not a crime, even in another country. Courts may or may not recognize the validity of a marriage that occurs outside the US, but getting an invalid marriage is not necessarily a crime.

"If the 53 year old has sex with the 6 year old, is he a sex offender."

It depends on location. Technically, under US Federal law, usually no, because the US (at the federal level) does not have a law forbidding rape in most circumstances (or even a universal murder law for that matter; such things are left to the states). EVERY state, however, would have laws prohibiting this from occurring within their boarders, so in any state the 53 year old would be a sex offender. Being validly married or not would be irrelevant. Additionally, it is a Federal crime in the US to travel across state or national boarders for the purpose of having sex with a minor.

Comment: Down voted for some clear errors.  Rape is illegal at the Federal Level under chapter 109a of the United States Code and is punishable by anything from a fine to life in prison.  The Federal Age of Consent is 18 and sex with someone under 18 is statutory rape (meaning you don't need to prove sex happened).  While the policy of the DOJ is to not prosecute criminal cases that states are perfectly capable of prosecuting, this does not prevent the Feds from prosecuting you for rape and in some instances, they have sole jurisdiction (such as on federal property or over state lines).

Comment: @hszmv - 'sex with someone under 18 is statutory rape (meaning _you don't need to prove sex happened_). ' are you sure about this?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My mistake... I had an interrupted thought.  Meant to say you don't need to prove that that the accused had consent from the victim.  Whether or not consent was given, the accused should not have been engaging in sexual relations period.

Comment: @hszmv: I agree with Michael Harvey that statutory rape does not means you don't have to prove that sex did not occur, it means you don't have to prove that one party did not consent. Also, the Federal Age of Consent is not 18 (I believe it is 16, as it is in the 31/50 US states). I will look into 109a.

Comment: @sharur:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_the_United_States#Federal_laws says it's 18.   You are correct that the majority of states list their age of consent at 16, and Romeo and Julieta exceptions exist (If two people who are close in age and one is under consent, it might not be prosecuted.).  The remaining 19 range from 17-18.  18 is commonly used throughout the nation, because its the oldest AND most well known, given the federal age AND age of consent in California (where most entertainment media and porn are made in the U.S.).

Comment: @hszmv Rape is almost never a federal crime. Chapter 109a of Title 18 is mostly limited to the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction of the United States, federal prisons, and state/local jails and prisons that hold federal prisoners.

Comment: @cpast U.S. Federal Law applies to any territory held by the U.S., however Federal policy is not to prosecute crimes when states/territories have jurisdiction and prosecute those crimes.  It's rare to see the feds bring the charges, but it's not impossible.

Comment: @hszmv The laws in question explicitly *don't* apply to the entire US. They don't say "sexual assault is illegal," they say "sexual assault is illegal inside the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction of the United States, inside a federal prison, or inside another prison where federal prisoners are held."

Comment: @cpast:   "territorial jurisdiction of the United States" EXPLICITLY confirms what I just said.   What do you think this language that you quoted means if not "Anywhere that is territory of the United States"?

Comment: @hszmv It's not "territorial jurisdiction", it's "special maritime and territorial jurisdiction" (i.e. the "special" is transitive). Essentially that phrase means "jurisdiction of the US that is not part of any state).

Comment: @sharur Or to phrase it another way It's "Territorial Waters AND Territorial Land"  not "Territorial Waters."  I mean, the documents where I found the law listed said it was illegal at the federal level at any part of the U.S.

Comment: @hszmv "Special territorial waters" and "special territorial land". E.g. what makes it "special" is that it doesn't fall under the jurisdiction of a (see the statues listed here: https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-663-special-maritime-and-territorial-jurisdiction). There is no "all encompassing" rape or murder law in the US. Instead we have state specific ones, and specific laws for "edge cases" like prisons, federal property where no state has jurisdiction, etc., as well as shipping, spacecraft, federal officers, etc.

Comment: @sharur You also fail to recognize the inclusion of crossing state lines under sub-section (C) which specifically speaks to statutory rape of the child.

Comment: @hszmv: See the last line of my answer.